# How to find a file I've been sent through Skype in linux?

Tags: linux, skype

I've sent a file to my friend in Skype a year ago. 
All of history is saved, How can I get file from it?

Answer (score 3):

The *history* in `skype` is saved locally in a SQLite database.
You can use SQLite or a [tool](http://www.sqlite.org/cvstrac/wiki?p=ManagementTools) to see its contents.

You can find your file in `~/.Skype/profilename`. Start from `main.db`.

Probably you will be able to see from where you take the file you sent to your friend, by I doubt you will find in your history the file itself.

From this answer of the [skype support](https://support.skype.com/en/faq/FA413/how-do-i-back-up-my-configuration-and-instant-message-history) for the windows version you can read

> Please note: Your contact list is stored on our servers and will not be lost as long as you always sign in with the same Skype Name. **Instant message histories** and other data are only stored on our servers for a short time

If you enabled [full logging](https://support.skype.com/en/faq/FA12321/how-do-i-create-log-files?), you probably have some encrypted file in the directory Logs in `~/.Skype/profilename/Logs`...

Comment: On Ubuntu, I found downloads in ~/snap/skype/common/. I believe I installed Skype using "Ubuntu Software:.